# Route stops working suddenly in LTS 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

On my Ubuntu server LTS 14.04. I setup a route through one gateway in my own network to another network.

```
route add -net 10.176.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.0.7
```

The route is working in general. The host 192.168.0.7 is reachable. The network 10.176.0.0/16 is reachable from 192.168.0.7. It happens that the route is working a long time but then suddenly stops working. The route is listed in the routing table (route -n) but doesn't work anymore. Even when I delete the route and add it once more it doesn't work till I restart the server. After this all goes fine till the moment when it suddenly stops working.

I could not find any log messages that are related to the problem. What should I do?

Comment: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Never route one address range towards another address range...  That'll always end up with trouble *eventually*.

#### Option 1: Both address spaces are on the same physical LAN and the same VLAN:

- Do a DHCP reservation on both DHCP servers of your MAC address
- Define both IP addresses statically on your machine
- Restart networking

#### Option 2: Both address spaces are on different physical LANs

- Add an additional NIC to your machine
- Do a DHCP reservation on the additional DHCP server of your additional MAC address
- Restart networking

If that's impossible:

- Add an additional IP address of the additional LAN statically on your additional NIC.

#### Option 3: Both address spaces are on the same physical LANs but different VLANs:

- Add an additional NIC to your machine
- Add the additional NIC/physical switch port to the additional VLAN
- Do a DHCP reservation on the additional DHCP server of your additional MAC address
- Restart networking

If that's impossible:

- Add an additional IP address of the additional LAN statically on your additional NIC.

**What probably happened** is that security got tightened behind your back and the "old" system doesn't work any more on a router level: talk to IT about the above solutions.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**